# Chartkick returning t is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, chartkick

When loading Chartkick, it returns

> Error Loading Chart: t is undefined

I have included `//= require Chart.bundle //= require chartkick` in application.js.

Comment: Have you restarted server after adding it in gemfile and in application.js

Comment: You've used `highcharts` label but the issue is not strictly related to it.